# Excel - Adding titles to both ends of an axis in a scatter plot

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, charts

I'm looking for a way to add axis titles to both ends of an axis in a scatter plot in Excel 2016 for Mac. So far I have titles only in the left and bottom parts and want to add the titles on the opposite sides.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind adding a screenshot example of what you'd like it to look like?

Comment: You can see the scatter plot I created on the embedded image. I'm trying to add labels on the opposite sides of the X and Y axes !(http://i59.tinypic.com/2crlnj8.png)